# Why does this shell command print all results in exactly one line?

Tags: bash, scripting, sh

Why does the following shell command print all results in one line?

```
echo $Nx $iiz | awk '{for(ii=1;ii<=$1;ii++) printf("%5.2f ",$2)}'
```

I want to print in a new line after each iteration

Answer (score 2):

Insert a new line `\n` in the `printf` statement.

Try one of these:

```
printf("\n%5.2f",$2)
```

or

```
printf("%5.2f\n",$2)
```